# `[1] == [1]` returns "false" and `[1] == 1` returns "true"?

Tags: javascript

I found this strange behavior in `javascript`.

```
var v1 = [1];
var v2 = [1];

v1 == v2  // false

v1 == 1 //true

[1] == [1] // false

1 == [1]    // true
```

why is it that `[1] == [1]`  returns `false`and `[1] == 1` returns `true`?

Comment: Arrays are objects, so [1] == [1] is comparing two separate objects. I'm unsure why [1] == 1.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/359494/720164

Comment: Forget about `==` in javascript. Use only `===`

Comment: `==` is basically evil in Javascript.  It is a good practice to avoid it nearly always unless you explicitly want a type conversion and you fully understand what it will do in all cases that your code will encounter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [spec says](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-abstract-equality-comparison) that if the two operands of `==` have the same type as each other (such as in the `[1] == [1]` case, where they both are type `Object`), then `==` behaves exactly like `===`. The two arrays are not the exact same object, so `false` is returned. Notice that:

```
var v1 = [1];
var v2 = v1;

v1 == v2; // true
```

When the operands have different types, they are both coerced. In the case of `1 == [1]` Rule 10 from the link above applies first and the array is converted to a primitive, by its `toString()` which returns `'1'`. Then rule 6 applies (converting the string `'1'` to the number `1`), and the comparison becomes `1 == 1`, and finally they have the same type and are compared with `===`. Obviously `1 === 1` evaluates to true.

Comment: @DyrandzFamador Yes, you should almost always use `===`. The `==` variant should be used carefully and always with a comment describing the reason for the implicit cast. It's almost always better to use `===` and explicitly convert between types before comparing eg. using `+str` or `parseInt( str, 10 )` to convert a string to a number.